# Different wording with mouse over when tagging URLs

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I'm producing an accessible PDF in InDesign and need the mouse over wording of URLs to read more descriptive than just the URL address.

Can this be done InDesign or is it a post-production process in Acrobat?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to do it in images, you should look for a trick to insert the URL as an image.

- Select a frame with an image
- **Menu Object** > **Object Export Options**
- Select **Alt Text** tab
- Choose **Custom**
- Enter the text in the text field

[image: barbie]